# Where to enter information into Get request (https)?

Tags: https, get, request

I want to get all price levels for crypto order book data from the Quoine Exchange. With this https-request I can only get the default 20 price levels: 
https://api.quoine.com/products/1/price_levels/

Somehow, I need to include the 'full' parameter in my request and set it to 1:
https://developers.quoine.com/#get-a-product

Where do I have to insert this parameter in my request?

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `https://api.quoine.com/products/1/price_levels/?full=1` ...? Duh.

Answer (score 0):

To add a parameter to a GET request you can use ? and &.

For example:

`https://api.quoine.com/products/1/price_levels?full=1`

And if you need to do more than one parameter

`https://api.quoine.com/products/1/price_levels?full=1&moreparam=1`